# String IdentityHashMap vs HashMap performance

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, hashtable

Identity HashMap is special implementation in Java which compares the objects reference instead of `equals()` and also uses `identityHashCode()` instead of `hashCode()`. In addition, it uses `linear-probe hash table` instead of `Entry list`.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(); 
Map<String, String> iMap = new IdentityHashMap<>();
```

Does that mean for the `String` keys `IdentifyHashMap` will be usually faster if tune correctly ?

See this example:

```
public class Dictionary {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/usr/share/dict/words"));

        String line;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(line);
        }
        System.out.println("list.size() = " + list.size());
        Map<String, Integer> iMap = new IdentityHashMap<>(list.size());
        Map<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>(list.size());

        long iMapTime = 0, hashMapTime = 0;

        long time;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            iMap.put(list.get(i), i);
            time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            iMapTime += time;
            time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            hashMap.put(list.get(i), i);
            time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            hashMapTime += time;
        }

        System.out.println("iMapTime = " + iMapTime + " hashMapTime = " + hashMapTime);
    }

}
```

Tried very basic performance check. I am reading dictionary words (235K) & pushing into the both maps. It prints:

```
list.size() = 235886
iMapTime = 101 hashMapTime = 617
```

I think this is very good improvment to ignore, unless I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: As per java docs "This class is not a general-purpose Map implementation! While this class implements the Map interface, it intentionally violates Map's general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when comparing objects. This class is designed for use only in the rare cases wherein reference-equality semantics are required.", so Ideally you should not use it just for performance improvement... also can you please explain hw much data you have that you need performancei mprovement over hasmap.. dont go for premature optimisations...

Comment: If I am not wrong `String == String ` check is exactly same as `String.equal(String)` method, so I think it does not matter in this case.  So is the  `linear-probe hash table` will provide improvement over reguler entry Set ?  I am just curious about this, so doesn't have exact count, but we can consider may be 5K +  strings ?

Comment: no.. string == string is not same as String.equal(string).. try this String s1= "abc"; String s2=new String("abc");.. print (s1==s2)...

Comment: also do you see any performance issues if you use hashmap with 5K+ strings ?

Comment: Thanks for correcting, my assumption was wrong

Comment: I've done some quick experiments. I didn't use proper benchmarking, so take these results with a pinch of salt, but `IdentityHashMap` was about 20% faster for my test program. However, I completely agree with coder. You should almost certainly not use an `IdentityHashMap`.

Comment: Thanks, what kind of problem one can face with IdentityHashMap vs  HashMap ? Especially the user aware about reference-equality semantics.

Comment: You'll come across all sorts of problems. If you use a `String` key. In order to retrieve the item later, you'll need exactly the same instance, not just an equal string, otherwise you won't be able to get the item out again.

Comment: This is true, but what if we just want to find duplicate/unique objects in the list or similar kind of quick operation ?

Comment: It depends what you mean by duplicate. If you mean strings that are `equal`, to remove duplicates from a `List<String>`  you can do `list = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(list));`. If you mean strings that are `==` I guess an `IdentityHashMap` would be the correct intermediate object, but I can't imagine why you would mean `==`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How does `IdentityHashMap<String,?>` work?

To make `IdentityHashMap<String,?>` work for arbitrary strings, you'll have to `String.intern()` both the keys you `put()` and potential keys you pass to `get()`. (Or use an equivalent mechanism.)

*Note: unlike stated in @m3th0dman's answer, you don't need to `intern()` the values.*

Either way, interning a string ultimately requires looking it up in some kind of hash table of already interned strings. So unless you had to intern your strings for some other reason anyway (and thus already paid the cost), you won't get much of an actual performance boost out of this.

#### So why does the test show that you can?

Where your test is unrealistic is that you keep the exact list of keys you used with `put()` and you iterate across them one by one in list order. Note (the same could be achieved by inserting the elements into a `LinkedHashMap` and simply calling `iterator()` on its entry set.

#### What's the point of `IdentityHashMap` then?

There are scenarios where it is guaranteed (or practically guaranteed) that object identity is the same as `equals()`. Imagine trying to implement your own `ThreadLocal` class for example, you'll probably write something like this:

```
public final class ThreadLocal<T> {
   private final IdentityHashMap<Thread,T> valueMap;
   ...
   public T get() {
       return valueMap.get( Thread.currentThread() );
   }
}
```

Because you know that threads have no notion of equality beyond identity. Same goes if your map keys are enum values and so on.

Comment: Is this mean we can use singleton classes with the Identity Hash map quite safely with performance boost ?

Comment: @Himanshu It can be used safely with all instance-controlled classes. Then again, in practice most of these classes have very few instances (an enum is unlikely to have more than 100 values, thread count could rise above that, but not by much) and a very fast `equals()` implementation (usually based on object identity), so the performance gain with IHM is negligible.

Answer (score 4):

You will see significantly faster performance on IdentityHashMap, however that comes at a substantial cost.

You must be absolutely sure that you will never ever have objects added to the map that have the same value but different identities.

That's hard to guarantee both now and for the future, and a lot of people make mistaken assumptions.

For example

```
String t1 = "test";
String t2 = "test";
```

`t1==t2` will return true.

```
String t1 = "test";
String t2 = new String("test");
```

`t1==t2` will return false.

Overall my recommendation is that unless you absolutely critically need the performance boost and know exactly what you are doing and heavily lock down and comment access to the class then by using IdentityHashMap you are opening yourself up to massive risks of very hard to track down bugs in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can do something like this to make sure you have the same instance of the string representation:

```
public class StringIdentityHashMap extends IdentityHashMap<String, String>
{
    @Override
    public String put(String key, String value)
    {
        return super.put(key.intern(), value.intern());
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends String> m)
    {
        m.entrySet().forEach(entry -> put(entry.getKey().intern(), entry.getValue().intern()));
    }

    @Override 
    public String get(Object key)
    {
        if (!(key instanceof String)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return super.get(((String) key).intern());
    }

    //implement the rest of the methods in the same way
}
```

But this won't help you very much since `intern()` calls `equals()` to make sure the given `String` exists or not in the String pool so you end up with the performance of the typical `HashMap`.

This, however will only help you to improve memory and not CPU. There is no way to achieve better CPU usage and to be sure your program is correct (without possible using some internal knowledge of JVM which might change) because Strings can be in String pool or not and you cannot know if they are in without (not implicitly) calling `equals()`.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, IdentityHashMap can be SLOWER. I am using Class objects as keys, and seeing a ~50% performance INCREASE with HashMap over IdentityHashMap.

IdentityHashMap and HashMap are different internally, so if the equals() method of your keys is really fast, HashMap seems better.